# move_uploaded_file do not work and don't know what else to check

Tags: php

I have a problem,

my move_uploaded_file does not work. the file size is less then what php.ini let me upload. It is in TMP memory, print_r($_FILES) shows me everything is fine and the path is right.

I don't know what else can go wrong? (considering it works fine on my other pages)

```
<?php
$bannername='banner_'.strtolower($_GET["system"]).'.'.$uploadformat;
$destination='style/pictures/'.$bannername;
$move=move_uploaded_file($_FILES["banner"]["tmp_name"], $destination);
if($move) {
}
?>
```

Edit : The function give me a result = False, however it still move the picture correctly....

Comment: should probably make destination as absolute path...not sure what it's relative to. you can use `__DIR__` to get the directory of the PHP script.

Comment: Is there a warning message? The problem is most likely permissions on the directory you're trying to move to.

Comment: I cannot move it to any file ... not just this one.
Don't know what _DIR_ is ... how should I use it?

Comment: it is strange.. it moves the file correctly but it still give me a false result while the pic has correctly be moved ....

Comment: `__DIR__` can be used like this : `$destination = __DIR__ . '/style/pictures/'.$bannername;`. Furthermore, I suggest that you enable error reporting by putting `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL),` after the opening PHP tag.